# Herencia en Java, atributo tipo que tendrá como valor clases hijas

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Estoy haciendo una clase abstracta Vehículo, que tendrá de subclases: moto, coche, camioneta y autocaravana.

El problema es que la clase vehículo tiene un atributo "tipo" que será un valor entre sus hijas  (moto, coche, camioneta y autocaravana).

No entiendo muy bien como hacer eso, puedo hacer esto?

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {

protected Vehiculo tipo;

public Vehiculo(Vehiculo tipo) {

this.tipo = tipo;


}


}
```

Comment: Hola Nico, como poder, se puede hacer, siempre y cuando le pases una cadena, no una instancia de la clase, pero no le veo ningún sentido, si quieres saber el tipo de una **Moto** se lo preguntas, con **getClass()**...

Comment: Tienes un atributo llamado `tipo` de tipo `Vehiculo`. Sin embargo, esto no es necesario ni recomendado, ya que el **propósito** de la clase abstracta es servir como una base común para sus subclases, y no tiene sentido tener una referencia a sí misma como atributo. Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar una variable de tipo `String` en lugar de una referencia a `Vehiculo` (como te comentan arriba).

Comment: Vale gracias, entonces lo hago tipo String y en el constructor limito a que las cadenas de texto sean: "moto" || "coche" || "camioneta" || "autocaravana" y elevo excepción si me dan otra cadena de texto distintas a esas?


Entiendo que el atributo tipo es para eso acorde a este enunciado que estoy realizando:

Clase ‘Vehiculo’, que tenga como atributos marca, modelo,
kilometraje (número inicializado a cero que sólo puede incrementarse en positivo),
matrícula, precio (euros por km recorrido, es un float), tipo (será un valor entre los
siguientes: moto, coche, camioneta y autocaravana)

Comment: en java no existe la posibilidad de definir atributos abstractos para luego ser implementados en las clases hijas. lo que podrías hacer es definir un método abstracto en vehiculo que retorne el tipo de vehiculo. cada clase concreta sabrá que tipo es. a pesar de eso, no creo que sea una buena estrategia realmente. tal vez si editas el post indicando con un poco más de detalle que estás intentando hacer, podamos sugerirte una mejor forma de resolverlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Si los nombres de las clases cohinciden con los nombres de los Tipos, puedes hacer algo asi:

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {
    protected String tipo;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private int anio;
    private String color;
    
    public Vehiculo(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.color = color;
        this.tipo=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

```
public class Moto extends Vehiculo {

    public Moto(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color) {
        super(marca,modelo,anio,color);
    }
}
```

2.- Si no coinciden, pues se lo ingresas al constructor a mano

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {
    protected String tipo;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private int anio;
    private String color;
    
    public Vehiculo(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color,String tipo) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.color = color;
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }
}
```

```
public class Moto extends Vehiculo {

    public Moto(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color) {
        super(marca,modelo,anio,color,"Moto");
    }
}
```

3.- O mejor aun ocupar `enum`

```
public abstract class Vehiculo {
    protected Tipo tipo;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private int anio;
    private String color;
    
    public Vehiculo(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color,Tipo tipo) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.color = color;
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }
    
    public enum Tipo{
        Moto, Coche, Camioneta, Autocaravana 
    }
}
```

```
public class Moto extends Vehiculo {

    public Moto(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String color) {
        super(marca,modelo,anio,color,Tipo.Moto);
    }
}
```

---

Ahora bien, todo esto tiene sentido siempre y cuando las clases Moto, Coche, Camioneta, etc tengan alguna diferencia en su implementación más allá del "Tipo". Es decir

1. Si `tipo` es solo un dato, no creas más clases y te quedas solo con la clase "Vehiculo"
2. Si `tipo` además de ser un dato, cambia la lógica entre clases, digamos que tiene una función `calcularPrecio` cuyo algoritmo es distinto entre si es una Moto o un Coche, ahí estaría bien crear distintas clases hijas